# Call Delegate Method Prior to View Dismissal

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates, modalviewcontroller

I have a modal view controller presented and just before I dismiss it, I need to call a delegate method which tells the parent view controller to update. (As methods like `viewWillAppear` are not called when dismissing a modal view controller).

So my code looks like this:

```
[delegate addEquipmentDidSave:YES];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Very simple. Send a message back, saying, update now! And then just dismiss the view. However, while both of these lines are called, the delegate method never runs. So I check that the delegate it set correctly. When I present the modal view I set the delegate, so its all connected.

Its as if the delegate method isn't getting a chance to run before the view is dismissed. Is this possible? What do you think might be the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the delegate is set when you come to run the code?

Comment: If delegate related things are fine, just try to dismiss view inside delegate method.?

Comment: @C_X Why? when there is a completion block that can be used in the dismissal method already?

Comment: @Abizern completion block will run after the view dismissal, and in question josh want that it should update view first and then dismiss other modal view. That's why I said to test if every thing else is fine.

Comment: Can't say exactly without seeing `addEquipmentDidSave`'s body, but I think that it's not updated, because it in background under modal view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before calling your delegate method first check whether it's available or not

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addEquipmentDidSave:)] )
{
    NSLog("Yes it's available");
    [self.delegate addEquipmentDidSave:YES];
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I never knew how to make use of `respondsToSelector`, led me to the problem! Turns out I was presenting the modal view from two places. Resulting in only one setting the delegate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see that last parameter, the one called `completion`? That block is called after the view controller is dismissed. Do what you want to do in there.